# python requests returns form itself not result

Tags: python, python-requests

Starting from http://webapps.nyc.gov:8084/CICS/fin1/find001i

```
import requests
params = {'FBORO':'Manhatten','FHOUSENUM':'300','FSTNAME':'Madison Avenue'}
p = requests.post("HTTP://webapps.nyc.gov:8084/CICS/fin1/find001i",data=params)
print(p.text)
```

I am getting the same page back instead of the result of my search.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBORO is a select field, it maps the displayed string values to an integer value. So Manhatten in this situation is sent as '1'.
Your params should look like this:

```
params = {'FBORO': '1', 'FHOUSENUM': '300', 'FSTNAME': 'Madison Avenue'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the params in a wrong way.

Following is the correct one:

```
params = {'FBORO':1,'FHOUSENUM':300,'FSTNAME':'Madison Avenue'}
```

You've to put `300` is a number, not as a String. And `1` instead of `Manhattan`

Comment: Hello, I have put in the params as you suggested with the 300 as number, but still the same result.   When I print(p.text), I get the same page back as the one I started from.

Comment: No. I'm getting a different HTML. Not the same one. Can you check again?